# How to create a binomial posterior distribution using R?

Tags: r, self-study, bayesian, binomial-distribution

So I am trying to solve the following problem computationally:
[image]

So I came up with the following general formula:

$P( p = x_j | k = successes , n = trials ) = \frac {x_j^{k}(1-x_j)^{n-k}P(p=x_j) } {\sum_{i=1}^{10}{x_j^{k}(1-x_i)^{n-k}P(p=x_i)}}$

So to answer part b, I want to write a generalized R function for this posterior distribution using prior distribution supplied. Something like $compute( n = trials , p = one\,\, of the\,\, possible\,\, p\,\, values ,  k = successes ) = 0.34...$

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: @Xi'an I did find some very informative answers with R programming on this site ! Do you know if Stack Overflow supports Latex ?

Comment: Just did - it doesn't seem to. And I can't post this picture b/c I don't have enough points. I am really in a bad situation...

Comment: Can you tell us where and why you get stuck in the R programming?